# How to query this MySQL table in the most performant way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a MySQL table that was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `my_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `my_boolean_field` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table is very large. It has approximately 10 million rows in it. `my_boolean_field`'s only possible values are `1`, `0` and `null`.

Now separately, I have a list of 500 IDs. Let's call this `my_list`. They are in a text file separated by newlines. The name of that file is `myfile.txt`.

I want to answer the following questions:

1. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is in `my_list` and my_boolean_field is null.
2. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==1.
3. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==0.
4. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is not in `my_list` and my_boolean_field is null.
5. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is not in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==1.
6. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is not in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==0.

What is the most performant way to get the above 6 counts??

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a full table scan, so this is probably the best solution:

```
select (case when id in (< your list >) then 'in' else 'out' end) as inlist,
       my_boolean_field, count(*)
from mytable t
group by (case when id in (< your list >) then 'in' else out' end),
         my_boolean_field;
```

If your list is in a table with an index, then you can use a `left join` on it.  However, MySQL optimizes searches for `in` with constant values (it uses a binary search).  So this is likely to be the fastest method.

Comment: Can u see my edit to the original question? The list of 500 IDs is in a text file. It is too long to fit into a single SQL statement.

Comment: @SaqibAli . . . You can construct a query from the 500 ids.  Or you can load them into a table with a primary key on the `id`.